# How to print all the result of each loop one time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

The program below asks for the user to enter "the number of test cases" and then to enter the number to make the operation on it. At the end I want to print the result for each operation in the loop.

This is the code:

```
test_case = int(raw_input()) # User enter here the number of test case
for x in range(test_case):
    n = int(raw_input())

while n ! = 1: # this is the operation
    print n,1, # 
    if n % 2 == 0:       
        n = n//2
    else:                 
        n = n*3+1
```

Below is the output if I enter "2" in the test case and 2 numbers in each case. For example 22 and 64 it will be like this:

```
2
22 # the first number of the test case 
22 1 11 1 34 1 17 1 52 1 26 1 13 1 40 1 20 1 10 1 5 1 16 1 8 1 4 1 2 1 # it prints the result immediately
64 # second test case
64 1 32 1 16 1 8 1 4 1 2 1 # it prints it immediately as the first
```

Below is the expected output:

```
2
22
64
```

The output after the user enters test case and all numbers of the test case is:

```
22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 
64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

How do I solve this?
Note: I tried to save result in a list and print it, but it prints all results in one line.

Comment: `for result in results: print result`

Comment: please can you put it in my code and add it please i do not know where i will put it and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Gets the number of test cases from the user
num_ops = int(raw_input("Enter number of test cases: "))

#Initilze the list that the test cases will be stored in
test_cases = list()

#Append the test cases to the test_cases list
for x in range(num_ops):
    test_cases.append(int(raw_input("Enter test case")))

#Preform the operation on each of the test cases
for n in test_cases:
    results = [str(n)]
    while n != 1: # this is the operation
        if n % 2 == 0:       
            n = n//2
        else:                 
            n = n*3+1
        results.append(str(n))
    print ' '.join(results)
```

Output exactly as you described but with input text prompts for added clarity.

```
enter number of test cases:  2
enter test case:  22
enter test case:  64
22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 
64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Comment: fantastic Many Thanks To You

Answer (score -2):

You have some problems with your indentation but I'm assuming that's only in the question and not in the real program.

So you want to first input all the test cases, execute them, and finally show the results.
To get the test cases you can do something like

```
num_test_cases = int(input())
test_cases = [0] * num_test_cases
for x in range(num_test_cases):
    test_cases.append(input())
```

After that you can execute you algorithm with the same code you have, but saving the results in a list (as you mentioned)

```
...
results = {}
for x in test_cases:
    n = int(x)
    results[x] = []
    while n != 1:
        results[x].append(n)
        ...
```

And you can finally print out your results

```
for result in results
    print(results)
```

Comment: your first code block doesnt reflect how he wants to input the test cases (asking for input for many times) and you should probably show how you initialized `results`/you didnt initialize `results` which means that calling `results[x]` will cause an error

Comment: no i doest fix it please can you upload my code again and put it the edits you make

Comment: change this `results = []` to `results = []*num_test_cases` and remove the `results[x] = []` line

Comment: That won't work, but my answer wasn't right either, now it should.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to print the sequence on the same line, you can do the following.

```
test_case=int(raw_input()) # User enter here the number of test case
for x in range(test_case):
    n=int(raw_input())
    results = []
    while n != 1: # this is the operation
        results.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:       
            n=n//2
        else:                 
            n=n*3+1
    print(' '.join(results)) # concatenates the whole sequence and puts a space between each number
```

I think this is pretty close to what you want.